# XML Schema mixed content

Tags: xml, xsd, mixed

I am writing an XML Schema for a database format for chess games. The moves are in a specific format which I validate with a regex; it looks something like this: `<move>Pe2e4</move>`. The `<move&>` element can also contain a `<variation>' element. The problem is, I can't simply do`mixed="true"` because I need to validate the move. Here is the relevant part of the schema file:

```
<xs:element name="move">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="moveType">
                <xs:attribute ref="time"/>
                <xs:attribute ref="comment"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="variation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

`moveType` is the type for moves that does the validation.

So can someone explain how I can:

1. have my move regex validation,
2. have my `<variation>` element, and
3. have my `time` and `comment` attributes.

BTW, the whole schema validates fine without the

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="variation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

part.

Comment: @alpha123: This is not a common schema, I think. It would be more clear to use two elements like `turn ::= ( move | variation? )`

Comment: @Alejandro: Well, I could arrange it differently, true, but I don't really see any reason to. I just want an element with a special type that can contain both text and an optional other element and some optional attributes. That's shouldn't be too hard, right?

Comment: @alpha123: The mixed content model is used mainly for text with some inline semantic. That's how everybody will undertand it. What's more readable? This `<move>Pe2e4<variation></variation></move>` or this `<turn><move>Pe2e4</move><variation></variation></turn>`?

Comment: The `<variation>` element is optional. And the purpose is for it not to be human readable but rather easily machine processable.

Comment: @alpha123: I think Alejandro is making a valid point here - mixed content is not generally any benefit if you want machine readability. As soon as you start introducing mixed content models, you reduce the extent to which it is possible to validate the content. Really, you should only consider mixed content if you have no other choices. The only place it is generally correct to use it is when you are marking up a text.

Comment: @Nic Gibson: Well, perhaps I'll change it. The reason it is mixed right now is so that I can easily tell which move a variation belongs to. What I might do is simply have the variation element right after the move it belongs to. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reorganizing the schema thanks to the advice of Alejandro and Nic Gibson. The <variation> element is now outside of the <move> element.